# what happened about "Main freelist: size is 0 but should be 2" in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

In sqlite3,I get an err

```
SQLITE_CORRUPT:database disk image is malformed
```

Then check it ,tells

```
*** in database main ***
Main freelist: size is 0 but should be 2
```

So what happend?

Comment: Something messed up its internal recordkeeping. See https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html for common causes.

Comment: I means what's wrong but not why